# Can't change notification sound Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, audio, notifications

I can't stand the default Linux Mint notification sound and want to change it.

I have downloaded an .mp3 of the sound I want, it did not show up when choosing a file to change the sound to. I then converted it to .oga with ffmpeg to match the other sound files used. The new .oga file sounds as it did as a .mp3. But it is still not visible when selecting a new sound for notifications.

What could be the issue and how can I resolve it?

Edit:
I have now also tried setting the notification file like so:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.sounds notification-file '/usr/share/mint-artwork/sounds/notification2.oga'
```

This shows in the sound settings now but does not work, I can also see the .mp3 I converted it from too, but when I choose to filter the files by "Sound files" in the bottom right, it hides the 2 files again. I have noticed the .oga I created is approximately 10 times larger than any of the system sounds, and the .mp3 is around twice as large.

Edit after answer:
Would be nice if someone could explain why .ogg works and why .oga doesn't when it is the file format used by the other default sounds?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I instead converted the file to .ogg instead of .oga. This works fine now.